# Generate xml using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Suppose that I have a class that looks like below,
how do I create xml like below using LINQ to XML?

```
public class Order
{
  public string OrderNo {get; set;}
  public string ItemId {get; set;}
  public string ItemDesc {get; set;}
  public int Qty {get; set;}
}
```

```xml
<orders>
  <orderid>
     <orderno>1</orderno>
     <itemid>W001</itemid>
     <itemdesc>C# T-Shirst</itemdesc>
     <quantity>2</quantity>
  </orderid> 
  <orderid>
     <orderno>2</orderno>
     <itemid>W002</itemid>
     <itemdesc>XML T-Shirt</itemdesc>
     <quantity>1</quantity>
  </orderid>
</orders>
```

Comment: Instead of LINQ to XML... the more suitable fit would be an XML serializer... and pretty trivial to do.

Comment: @vivek I whole-heartedly disagree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need linq to generate this xml, you could use linq to generate a `collection` and serialize the collection in a xml file.

Before serializing, you should add the `Serializable` attribute in your class:

```
[Serialize]
public class Order
{
  public string OrderNo {get; set;}
  public string ItemId {get; set;}
  public string ItemDesc {get; set;}
  public int Qty {get; set;}
}
```

Take a look here how to customize your serialization (using attributes):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.80).aspx

Create a method like this to serialize:

```
public statc void SerializeOrders(Order[] orders, string path)
{
   XmlSerializer parse = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Order[]));
   using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
   {
      parse.Serialize(writer, orders);
      writer.Close();
   }
}
```

And deserialize:

```
public statc Order[] Deserialize(string path)
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Order[]));
    Order[] result;
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path))
    {
        result = (Order[]) ser.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And use it:

```
// get the collection
var orders = (from o in Queryable<Order>
             where o.Something
             select o).ToArray();

    // serializing in xml
    SerializeOrders(orders, "C:\\result.xml");

   // deserializing the xml
   var serializedOrders = Deserialize("C:\\result.xml");
```

Comment: thanks for your respond, in my real requirement it needs to add lots of static attributes as data types, namespace. Can I achieve this using Linq to XML?

Comment: I do think so, Linq To XML is just to read xml using linq statements. To save it, you could use serialization (in my option, easyly to do) or XmlDocument and XmlWriter to do (fine but dificult to do).

Comment: You can use LINQ to XML to create and save XML and have much simpler code than all of the XML Serialization stuff.

Answer (score 23):

While you can use XmlSerialization, there are quite a number of cases where using LINQ to XML is just as easy and doesn't lock your class implementation into a single serialization scheme. Here's a bit of code to handle your request.

```
var xOrders = new XElement("orders",
    from o in Orders
    select new XElement("orderid", 
        new XElement("orderno", order.OrderNo),
        new XElement("itemid", order.ItemId),
        new XElement("itemdesc", order.ItemDesc),
        new XElement("quantity", order.Qty)));

xOrders.Save(targetPath);
```

Comment: This actually answers the question that was asked.

Answer (score 2):

You have to respect the hierarchy.

Serializing this XML, we'll have something like this:

```
<Order>
   <OrderNo></OrderNo>
   <ItemId></ItemId>
   ...
<Order>
```

I think in this case, you will have to write on your own reading the object and generating the XML using XmlDocument, XElement or a StringBuilder for example.

Comment: Thanks Riba, I think XmlDocument is the way to go